# Change the label background-color when a checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to implement a static checkbox (without query/script/function) like this:

By clicking the checkbox box, it should change to that brown color (like the `name` box), and by clicking again it goes to normal (like `price`)

[image]

```css
.checkbox-round {
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  /*background-color: white !important;*/
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  /*background-color: white;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*border: 3px solid #ddd;*/
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-round:checked {
  background-color: #A97B47 !important;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="filterByName" type="checkbox" checked class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 button checkbox-round" name="filterByName"  value="name" placeholder="name">
  name
</label>
```

Comment: This should not be a checkbox to begin with. You don't have a "Value X: Yes or No?" choice here, you have a "X or Y?" choice here. So use two grouped radio buttons, each with their own label - one saying "Name", the other saying "Price". Then clicking on those labels, will toggle those radio buttons. The radio buttons themselves can be visually hidden. If you place the labels behind the radio buttons, you can format the label based on the radio button state directly, using the _adjacent sibling combinator_. (`:has()` would also work, but is not supported in Firefox without using flags yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. move the input outside the label
2. add the `for` attribute to the label to connect it to the checkbox
3. hide the checkbox with `display: none`
4. style the label instead of the checkbox
5. Apply the `background-color` and `color` changes by using the `+` combinator

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #A97B47;
  color: white;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="filterByName" type="checkbox" name="filterByName"  value="name" placeholder="name" checked>
<label for="filterByName">name</label>
```

PS: As @CBroe already said in the comments. It should be radio buttons as you can only sort by 1 selection not multiple. The technique remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :has() test on your css

```css
.checkbox-round {
  padding:10px 15px;
  /*background-color: white !important;*/
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  /*background-color: white;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*border: 3px solid #ddd;*/
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input{
  appearance: none;
  display:none;
}

.checkbox-round:has(> input:checked){
  background-color: #A97B47 !important;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-round">
  <input type="checkbox" checked name="checkbox"/>
  Name
</label>
```

Comment: Note that `:has()`still has very limited support. It only works in up-to-date browsers and Firefox with the experimental mode flag enabled.